# Call ActionResult in the Area controller from a shared view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

From the *Layout.cshtml* which is inside the *Views* folder (outside Areas), I need to resolve the action method of a controller created inside an Area.

I have a few custom routes defined, but the default route is as always:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
              new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Eg:

**Area** - *Test*, **Controller** - *HomeController*, **Action Method** - *Index*

`@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { Area = "Test" })` returns an empty string.
`@Html.ActionLink("Test link", "Index", "Home")` returns an empty string.

`@Html.RouteLink("Test Link", "default",  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" })` returns in an error

> A route named 'default' could not be found in the route collection.

Just to clarify, this action doesn't need to be invoked using a custom route. It will never be directly accessible via a URL, so the default route should do fine.

I am bummed. How can I resolve the action?

Answer (score 0):

Under the same namespace add following class

```
public class TestAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Test";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Test_default",
            "Test/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Under Global.asax make sure to have RegisterAllAreas()

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();            
    }
```

Comment: I have that in.